# What does it mean to be *equipped with the final topology with respect to a function $f$?*

Tags: general-topology

> What does it mean to be *equipped with the final topology with respect to a function $f$?*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map) says a surjection $f:X\to Y$ is a quotient map if it is onto and $Y$ is equipped with the final topology with respect to $f$.

I get what the finest topology is.

I get that the canonical $f:X\to X/{\sim}$ is a quotient map.

I get that this is like gluing points within each equivalence class together.

But I can't translate any of those things into the sentence above.

The following example will probably be helpful:

Let the boundary $B$ of the square $[0,1]^2$ be homeomorphic to the unit circle.

Let $f:\forall x\in B:x\mapsto B$

Then I think this is such an example.

This I should have that $B$ has the final topology with respect to $f$ but I can't see it.  What is its topology and how is that *with respect to $f$*?

Fundamentally I think I'm not appreciating the importance of open sets.  This may be because I have no experience of analysis.

Comment: If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a map where $X$ is a topological space, then the final topology on $Y$ with respect to $f$ is the finest topology on $Y$ making $f$ continuous. You can show that open sets for this topology are those $U\subseteq Y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: @Gaussian then my definition of $f$ is inadequate, right? Because I have to define it on some superset of $B$ to learn anything?

Comment: @Gaussian: How is that a comment and not an answer?

Comment: OP, your "example" is not even a well-defined function yet, as you don't specify its codomain. If its codomain is meant to be $\lbrace B\rbrace$, that's a singleton, and on singletons there is only one topology anyway. (Of course an interesting quotient map, gluing together parts of the boundary of the unit circle, which could serve as beginner's example, would be a totally different $f$.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: I put it in a comment because it seems that the OP's question contains several questions. My comment only answers one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_i, i \in I$ are topological spaces and $Y$ is a set and for each $i$, $f_i:X_i \to Y$ is a function, then the final topology with respect to $\{f_i\}_{i \in I}$ is the largest topology on $Y$ such that all $f_i$ become continuous.

This topology can be explicitly defined as

$$\{O \subseteq Y: \forall i \in I: f_i^{-1}[O] \text{ open in } X_i\}$$

and its properties are easily checked. The most known example is where we have just one function $f$ and we get the "quotient topology" on $Y$.

Another well-known one is when $Z=X\sqcup Y$ (disjoint union of two spaces $X$ and $Y$ and the so-called sum-topology is the final topology wrt the two inclusion maps $X \to Z$ and $Y \to Z$ (more spaces are possible).

It's a dual notion to the so-called initial topologies (on the common domain of a set of functions), which includes examples like subspace and product topologies.